# Disabling the April Fools chat box doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, fun, april-fools

There are two options in the April Fools "chat with an expert" window:

1. Not now
2. Never

I've clicked on `Never` many times, but it keeps popping up. How can I hide this box permanently?

Comment: Does the "Nevermind, I saw it again here." in the answer you just deleted mean that on the same site and in the same browser that you previously clicked "never", the box appeared again? That indeed should not be the case.

Comment: @balpha After I posted my answer I saw it again. that is why I deleted my answer. So, I clicked never twice on the same site!

Comment: In the same browser?

Comment: @balpha yes.. and without closing it.. and without deleting a cookie. the box appeared again now while I am talking to you

Comment: What browser is it? What do you see when you put `alert(localStorage.getItem("adviza:leavemealone"))` in your JS console?

Comment: `Timestamp: 4/1/2013 01:46:54 ص
Error: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMWindow.localStorage]
Source File: javascript:%20alert(localStorage.getItem("adviza:leavemealone"))
Line: 1`

Comment: FireFox 20 Beta

Comment: You do know today's date?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Did you actually read the question?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yes, I did. And my point still stands. The options can also be there to just **be there** and not-for-work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that you don't have localStorage available. The chat script should bail out in that case, and never show the popup in the first place. Why it doesn't do that I don't know, but given that you're running a beta browser, I'll assumes that this is one of the many niceties that happen in beta browsers and which are precisely the reason we don't support them.

Please let me know if you can reproduce this in a supported browser.

Comment: I cannot argue with over NINE THOUSANDS rep user. the problem only happens with this specific browser.

Comment: Yes. I just clicked on `Never` after reading the question. Now I am not able to chat with bots. (Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m).

Comment: And is there any option to re-chat with bots?

Comment: @hims056 just visit any other stackexchange website such as : http://stackexchange.com/ and you will see the message again. or use the same browser that I am using :P

Comment: @hims056 No UI, but you can just put `localStorage.clear()` into the JavaScript console.

Comment: I'm running Firefox 3.5, and the stupid non-joke does show and the "never" button does not work. Please do something about such annoying things next time you introduce any.

Comment: @tohecz why not IE6 on Windows 95? Come on you can't expect any site to work properly on ancient browsers.