# Get the expert back

Tags: support, april-fools

I clicked "never" and removed the "Chat with an Expert" *permanently*. Now what am I supposed to do all day?

How can I get the expert back?

I would ask this an expert instead of bothering you, but, well.

Comment: clear browser cache

Comment: Type "unicorn overflow" in the search box

Comment: What @Manishearth said, plus hit tab - you need to type "unicorn overflow", and then remove focus from the search box (without leaving the page).

Comment: @Jaydles: I think you have to clear your localStorage as well.

Comment: "unicorn overflow" and then "tab"...it is not working. Please let me access expert again. I beg.

Comment: @rapsalands is it still April 1?

Comment: No. So is it all gone completely?

Comment: @rapsalands see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174525/205264

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no UI for that but [you can just put `localStorage.clear()` into the JavaScript console.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174494/disabling-the-april-fools-chat-box-doesnt-work/174509?noredirect=1#comment-521779)