# Why was the decision made to make the 2019 April Fool's joke immediately activate?

Tags: support, april-fools, time-travel-mode

As far as I recall, every April Fool's prank that SE has made in recent years prior to this year has been *non-intrusive*, only showing up as a minor sidebar while not affecting the site's design much.

However, this year, the Time Travel Mode prank made *drastic, intrusive* changes to a site's design, which is *not* like previous April Fool's pranks. Additionally, it's enabled by default, which quite a few users have raised complaints with.

Last year's Quack Overflow and the "chat with an expert" from years back, by comparison, were simple buttons in the bottom right, with a pop-up prompt for users to activate it. The windows for each wouldn't activate immediately.

Why was the decision made to make this joke immediately activate, rather than keep it behind a prompt (much like the current "Back to the future" prompt) to activate it? In my opinion, it wouldn't have raised so many complaints, and it still would have been just as fun for users.

Comment: If one ask you "Do you want to try April fool?" then it will be meaningless since it will not be fool anymore!

Comment: This sounds like asking "Do you want to be fool?"

Comment: I wouldn't say that this one is any more intrusive than the other April Fools' pranks, save for the possible bug that disabling it only worked *per page*, rather than per site. All other pranks have been enabled by default, but note that it's only for registered users.

Comment: @Pandya It doesn't have to specifically mention April Fool's. Last year's Quack Overflow did a similar thing; a small icon on the bottom right with a prompt to activate it. Why not do the same thing here?

Comment: @CodyGray You may not have found it intrusive, but a lot of people did.

Comment: Are you asking because you're curious or because you don't like it all?

Comment: All April Fools jokes, ever, were enabled by default, otherwise it lose any meaning. But none was ever so intrusive. I agree they took it way too far this year.

Comment: @CodyGray this definitely is super-intrusive. It's still intrusive even if the disabler get fixed.

Comment: @rene I want to know if SE considered that the feature (as intended, not with bugs) would be friendly to all users and all computers, and decided to release it anyway.

Comment: You guys must not remember [Cornify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20477/the-fancy-and-amazing-april-fools-question)... I didn't say this one wasn't intrusive. It said it doesn't seem any more intrusive than previous pranks.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326014/what-testing-is-done-on-april-fool-pranks). Enabling it by default this year was a horrible choice.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not saying you're not speaking truth, but reminding me of cornify is definitely wrong :P

Comment: The better question would be the reason an April Fool's day joke is activated 12 hours before April 1st.

Comment: @Ramhound The SE team has already addressed that. It's active as long as it's April 1 anywhere in the world.

Comment: When I first saw that mess, I wondered if I was redirected to a clone site, followed by wondering if my computer was suddenly being attacked or had been hacked.  I had to check the URL.  Definitely not the reaction you want.

Comment: How about an profile option to permanently disable all current and future April Fools related stuff?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That might benefit from being turned into a post/feature request

Comment: @Tinkeringbell There's a similar (if broader) [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174639/option-to-disable-all-april-fools-easter-eggs-winter-hats-and-similar-annoying) from a few years ago.

Answer (score 11):

Because no one would turn it on, it loses the element of surprise and bugs aside it would be pointless as an April fool's day joke.

It's a little on the nose, sure but having it off by default kinda defeats the point.

Comment: This is an incorrect justification. People were clearly willing to turn on Quack Overflow, "chat with an expert", and those other pranks. Why wouldn't they turn on this one?

Comment: All of which were turned on by default

Comment: No. The chat window of "chat with an expert" wasn't immediately displayed; you had to click on it to show it. Neither was the dialog for Quack Overflow; you had to explicitly click that as well to activate it.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog The different between this and Quack Overflow is that Quack Overflow was non-intrusive and fun to play around with. This is just pure visual diaherra on a screen - not the type of thing I want plastered on my screen when I'm trying to research something. And I know that I can turn it off, but it keeps turning itself back on.

Comment: I wonder... who refuses a good laugh *with* friends when given the opportunity? And what about a laugh *by* friends?